# Vague JavaFX NullPointerException error message

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, nullpointerexception

Well, I'm writing this simple JavaFX application for school, where we are finding the shortest way out of a maze from a given point. However, for fun, I decided to take it a step further and have some fun. Instead of simply coloring the rectangles which are part of the solution I tried to make a pacman which eats his way out of the maze. The weird part is that sometimes it works perfectly, other times it simply stops up and spam this error message in the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2289)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

As you can see there is no actual pointer to my code where the error should be, so I'm kinda confused, not to mention what the error is supposed to be.

I'm using a thread in one of the classes to animate the pacman, however the code that actually is changing the `Image` is in a `Platform.runLater()`, so it shouldn't be causing any problems. Besides this, I'm pretty lost, so please do give me some pointers to where the problem might be or help me interpret this error message.

Here is the thread I'm using for animation. Only posting the run method and the instance variables, however there is a simple setter for the `walking` boolean and a constructor which sets the `Image` array, frames.

Instance variables:

```
boolean walking = false;
Image[] frames;
```

run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    walking = true;
    for(int i = 0; walking; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        final Image img = frames[i % frames.length];
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setFill(new ImagePattern(img));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added thread code

Comment: That sounds like something is wrong with your multithreading. It's pretty much impossible to help unless you can post some code that reproduces the issue. FWIW I probably wouldn't use thread at all for something like that - I'd consider an `AnimationTimer` first. (Though "do it a different way" is, I accept, not really an answer to the question.)

Comment: Added the multithreading code

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that (though you should definitely be using the animation API for that - using a thread is overkill, you only need a timeline or a transition). There isn't any other threading anywhere?